# gcc: no input files

Tags: gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu subsystem in Windows 10 and I also installed gcc. I wrote a simple Hello world C program and saved it in documents. When I try to compile this program I get this answer:

```
Tony316@DESKTOP-2ONG1CO:~$ gcc Hello.c -o Hello
gcc: error: Hello.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.
```

I think I have to put my Hello World program in the correct file for gcc to find it, but I don't know how to compile it.

I know this question may have been asked before from users that run only ubuntu in their PC, but I am running it on Windows 10 and I couldn't find anything relevant

Comment: "saved it in documents."? But you're telling `gcc` that it's in the current directory. What does `gcc Documents/Hello.c -o Hello` produce.

Comment: I run it and this is what comes out: Tony316@DESKTOP-2ONG1CO:~$ gcc Documents/Hello.c -o Hello
gcc: error: Documents/Hello.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it (this is a result of some quick research), the Bash environment in Windows has two separate "home" directories: one containing your Windows files and the other containing files such as .bashrc and other traditional home directory files found in Linux. To navigate to your Windows Document folder type: `cd /mnt/c/Users/yourusername/Documents/`. From there, compile your program using gcc with `gcc Hello.c -o Hello`.

Comment: I finally figured it out and found the correct path. Thank you!